# Почему после глобальной установки пакета typescript в vs code при вызове компилятора tsc возникает ошибка?

Tags: typescript

Начинаю изучать typescript. Установил пакет typescript в vs code глобально, написав в терминале npm install -g typescript. При проверки версии tsc -v возникает ошибка.

> Имя "tsc" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла скрипта или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность написания имени, а также наличие и правильность пути, посл
> е чего повторите попытку.
> Подскажите, как решить данную проблему?
> Node.js и npm установлены (Версия Node 13.14.0, npm 6.4.14)

Comment: Может надо терминал перезапустить?

Comment: Пробовал перезапускать терминал и vs code, все равно выдает эту ошибку

Answer (score 0):

https://habr.com/ru/company/vk/blog/530712/

попробуй:

```
npx tsc -v
```

или

```
yarn tsc -v
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

убедись что у тебя прописан npm в path вп переменных среды если это windows